# How to import from different bundle created with webpack

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I have two project using webpack. Now I want to bring one project as module of other project. I can get the two bundle created but don't know how to import from the other bundle.

Elaborating a bit:-
Lets say the other file from which i want to import looks like as follows:-

> index2.js (Bundled as bundleTwo)

```
import SomeCompoent from "./components/SomeCompoent/SomeCompoent";
module.exports = {SomeCompoent}
```

and in the file (is in another bundle - bundleOne) below I want to import the component (somecomponent):-

> index1.js (in bundleOne)

```
import {SomeCompoent} from "bundleTwo";
```

but here bundleTwo is undefiend

Any help is highly appreciated

Comment: I have the same issue, any help?

Comment: I answered it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way that I have figured out myself, is that using alias this can be achieved.

To make this line `import {SomeCompoent} from "bundleTwo";` work, bundleTwo can be defined in alias :-

```
 config:{
     resolve: {
        alias: {
          "bundleTwo": path.join(__dirname, "<path_to_the_bundleTwo>")
        }
   ....
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, where should i put this? inside the webpack config file?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use webpack only,then just set the libraryTarget to 'umd' in bundletwo webpack configuration.

In order to be able to import this module, you need to export your bundle.

```
 output: {
        libraryTarget: 'umd',// make the bundle export
        filename: "index.js",
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
    }
```

However, this can also be achieved by just using Babel to transpile your ES6 code to ES5 code.

`babel index2.js --out-file dist/index2.js`

Now set the main in package.json to "dist/index2.js"

Now you can use it like

```
import {SomeCompoent} from "bundleTwo";
```

You can also create a gulp script for that

```
gulp.task('js', function () {
    return gulp.src(['packages/**/*.js', "!**/*.test.js"])
        .pipe(babel({
            plugins: ['transform-runtime']
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});
```